# Find angle to a point

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to find the angle between a point and the left side of my camera's fov.

In the picture below the camera (Red dot) is looking towards a polygon (Green) with the fov of the camera represented as the blue lines.

[image: Birds eye view of what is happening]

I've tried to butcher some code together from my limited understanding of linear so I havent gotten far. I've tried atan2 as well, but it seems to give incorrect answers for what im looking for.

the info i have is:

```
the point(x,y) I'm evaluating
the camera(x,y)
line segment and angle representing the left side of the cameras fov
same for the right
```

How would i find the angle between the left angle and the point?
I'm going to use the calculation to find the angle to each of the points making up the polygon.

Below is a rough mock up ive been using to try to figure this out
the blue angle with the question mark is what im looking for

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The angle can be computer with **atan2()** function from **math**.

```
import math
dx = tgtx - camx
dy = tgty - camy
ang = math.atan2( dy, dx )
```

Note that this angle will be in radian units.

Comment: The value returned is the angle between the two points, not the angle in relation to the left line segment/angle... this doesnt actually solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own issue.
If anyone in the future is looking for the same answer below is the code witha short write up.

```
def get_angle(e, f, p):
    """
    :param e: Entity we're measuring from
    :param f: Fov arm endpoint
    :param p: Point we're getting the angle to
    :return:
    """
    a = np.array([e.pos.x, e.pos.y])
    b = np.array([f.x, f.y])
    c = np.array([p.x, p.y])
    ba = b - a
    bc = b - c
    cos_ang = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
    return np.arccos(cos_ang) * 10
```

This will create a line intersecting "e" and "f" then return how close point "p" is to that line.
I am running this in tandem with another solution to detect if the point is in view as you will recieve the same value if your camera angle is flipped 180